# How to stop dark mode from flashing white

Tags: html

My html code for my dark theme is flashing for about a millisecond and I don't know why it is doing it or how to correct it. I am new to html and I'm still learning. I am just looking for a way to stop it from flashing when I change to a different page from the navigation menu.

```
<link id="mystylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="light.css">

<title>This is my web page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Nav-Layout.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 

integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" 
      
crossorigin="anonymous">

<script type="text/javascript">

    var setTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme')
    console.log('theme:', setTheme)

    if (setTheme == null){
        swapStyle('light.css')
    }else{
        swapStyle(setTheme)
    }

    function swapStyle(sheet){
        document.getElementById('mystylesheet').href = sheet
        localStorage.setItem('theme', sheet)
    }
```

```
    <button class="btn btn-light" onclick="swapStyle('light.css')">Light Mode</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick="swapStyle('dark.css')">Dark Mode</button>




<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="Contact.html"> Contact </a></li>

</ul>


<p id="Par"> This is my Home page</p>
```

Comment: Is your default theme light?

Comment: I’ve had this problem before and it’s a combination of “network” latency, load times and execution order. The browser sees your style sheet for the light theme, loads it, and then later sees the dark theme and has to load it. I would recommend adding a link tag for both style sheets in the HTML, and use JavaScript to remove the one not in use, instead of using Jacascript to add the one.

Comment: Also recommend placing your script tag directly below both mystylesheet link element, before bootstrap and other elements. This will help reduce processing times.